# How to run unit tests for Generate Signed Bundle / APK action

Tags: android, android-testing, android-signing

How to automatically run unit tests before signing a bundle using "Build -> Generate Signed Bundle" action in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below configuration to your module's `build.gradle` file:

For unit tests:

```
afterEvaluate {
    bundleRelease.dependsOn testReleaseUnitTest
}
```

For both unit tests and instrumentation tests use:

```
afterEvaluate {
    bundleRelease.dependsOn testReleaseUnitTest, connectedAndroidTest
}
```

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'testReleaseUnitTest' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.